# Angular.element.after - Is there a way to make it cleaner?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the below directive being called on an input html element. For this reason the template can not propagate like usual because they new elements will be wrapped in an input tag, which, apart from being bad HTML, also hides it from the browser's view.

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        input: '=ngModel'
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
        var typeAheadHtml = angular.element('' +
            '<div>' +
                '{{input}}' +
            '</div>' +
        '');
        element.after($compile(typeAheadHtml)(scope));
    }
};
```

The above work's just fine, for now, becase the `typeAheadHtml` is simply a prototype to show that this works. Is there a way to maintain the seperation of concerns I love so much about AngularJS but maintain the functionality of an `element.after`. Is there any way to have the `typeAheadHtml` be a regular html file?

**ANSWER**

Thanks to DonJuwe for his help on this one. The correct way to keep the same behavior but maintain a separation of concerns is as follows:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
        $http.get('bawwf/templates/type-ahead-directive.html', {cache: $templateCache})
            .success(function(html) {
                element.after($compile(html)(scope));
            });
    }
```

The above grabs the data from the file contents from the `$templateCache`. Using the `$compile` provider as before works just fine from that point onwards.

Comment: You can put your *html* into a dedicated file using `templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html'` (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). I don't think there's a better way of appending the template to your `element` though.

Comment: @DonJuwe If I was to stick the `typeAheadHtml` into the seperate file, would I still be able to include it and then do the `element.after` on it? Something like `element.after($compile(urlToHtml)(scope));`?

Comment: yes, that is possible but you maybe have to do a request like this: `$http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache}).success(function(html) {  element.append(html); }`

Comment: Woah that looks crazy. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @DonJuwe Just dropping in to say this worked. I'll update the question with the answer you gave. Thanks loads! - Do you want to write it as an answer and I can accept it for other people coming to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your template by using `templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html'`. Afterwards, append get the hmtl and append it to the `element`:

```
$http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache}).success(function(html) {  
    element.append(html); 
}
```

More information: [API Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Thanks again, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your directive an element directive (`restrict: 'E'`), translating to an `input`-element with typeahead, passing all attributes down to the `input`-element. This way your DOM keeps a clear structure and your directive only modifies DOM in its own scope:

```
<typeahead type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..."></typeahead>
```

Comment: I would but we are supporting older browsers so we have to have `A` for the `restrict` :<

Comment: @Aleski so you are supporting IE8? There is a workaround to using element directives in IE8, so you could use that. However, keep in mind that Microsoft will drop support for all IE versions <11 enxt year

Comment: Is the work around a pain? Also in your solution, would the directive just have an input inside the view which would then have a directive on that input for the typeahead?

Comment: [This](http://www.softwaresweden.com/2013/05/28/angularjs-and-ie8-directive-that-compiles-html/) and [this](http://www.befundoo.com/blog/angularjs-directives-in-ie8/) article both suggest the same workaround, so I would assume it works (and it does not look ike too much pain). I also edited my answer to make clear what I mean, it would eb jsut one element directive which acts like a normal input by putting all its attributes (except for the typeahead-specific ones) onto an input element and adding the typeahead-area html.